# Android Paste Button

Tags: android

everything good?

I have a problem, at the time of creating a button with the action of pasting a text in an EditText. I've tried several different ways but it did not work. Does anyone have an idea of where the error is and how to solve it?

***ERROR: Error:(68, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable txtNome***

```
public class Pedidos extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static final int REQUEST_DIALOG_PHOTO = 1;
    private int havePhoto = 0;
    private View buttonColar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pedidos);
        CopiarColar();
    }

    private void CopiarColar() {
        buttonColar = findViewById(R.id.buttonColar);
        buttonColar.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {

            case R.id.buttonColar: colarDaAreaDeTransferencia();
                break;
        }
    }

    //Cola o texto que estava na área de transferência
    private void colarDaAreaDeTransferencia() {
        ClipboardManager Colar = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        txtNome.setText(Colar.getText());


        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCadastrar);
        final ImageView imgFoto = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgFoto);


        imgFoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                imgFoto.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
                Intent camera = ImagePicker.getPickImageIntent(getBaseContext());
                startActivityForResult(camera, REQUEST_DIALOG_PHOTO);
            }
        });

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText txtNome = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtNome);
                View buttonColar;


                int error = 0;

                if (txtNome.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    txtNome.setError("FALTOU O NÚMERO DA O.S");
                    txtNome.requestFocus();
                    error = 1;
                }

                if (error == 0) {
                    String URL = "http://meusite.com/insert_user.php";

                    String photoFile = "";

                    try {
                        photoFile = getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getBaseContext().getPackageName(), 0).applicationInfo.dataDir + "//photo//perfil.png";
                    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

                    }

                    Ion.with(getBaseContext())
                            .load(URL)
                            .setMultipartParameter("nome_user", txtNome.getText().toString())
                            .setMultipartFile("photo_user", new File(photoFile))
                            .asJsonObject()
                            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
                                    if (result.get("retorno").getAsString().equals("YES")) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "FOTO ENVIADA COM SUCESSO!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                    }
                                }
                            });
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_DIALOG_PHOTO){
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                Bitmap photoUser = ImagePicker.getImageFromResult(getBaseContext(), resultCode, data);
                ImageView imgFoto = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgFoto);
                imgFoto.setImageBitmap(photoUser);
                havePhoto = 1;

                // Grava foto pasta
                File diretorio = Environment.getDataDirectory();
                String path = "//data//" + getBaseContext().getPackageName() + "//photo//";

                diretorio = new File(diretorio, path);
                diretorio.mkdirs();

                OutputStream out = null;

                File outputFile = new File(diretorio, "perfil.png");

                try {
                    out = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
                    photoUser.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Por favor, selecione uma foto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The vairable doesn't exist.  You never declared it.

Comment: @GabeSechan  line 54 EditText txtNome = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtNome);

Comment: That's a local variable.  Wrong scope.  Variable was never declared.

Comment: @GabeSechan private EditText txtNome; I declare, error message has disappeared but when I press the paste button the App closes.

Comment: @GabeSechan java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at br.com.guilherme.gcmteste.Pedidos.colarDaAreaDeTransferencia(Pedidos.java:31)
                                                                               at br.com.guilherme.gcmteste.Pedidos.onClick(Pedidos.java:23)

Answer (score 1):

Make `EditText txtNome` a global variable.